# How can I copy a calendar event to another day?

Tags: calendar, copy-and-paste

Actually what the question says. I banged my head a lot to find an option to copy one calendar event from one day to another day but in vain. Am I missing something? I am using sharepoint from browser not outlook if it makes any difference.

Comment: you can drag and drop it, but that will move it.  I can't copy and paste it.

Comment: @Tally nice thought that I've missed; I tried all possible combinations dragging with control shift and alt (even win key) but nothing.

Comment: which version of sharepoint are you using !!

Comment: @cjs I don’t have the slightest idea! It’s maintained and imposed by the company. I’m just an end user. I will try to see if there is a means to learn. Oh how much I miss the simplicity of desktop apps; a Help>About usually could do.

Comment: does the URL says:  **YourCompanyName.sharepoint.com**  or something else !!

Comment: @cjs not it's the other way around: sharepoint.division.company.com

Answer (score 0):

Just connect your calendar to outlook and then you will be able to copy and paste.